# Bad substitution when running from cron

Tags: bash, variable-substitution

I have a function (notify_dba) that with two string args, a header and a body. (correction) <strike>Works well from shell prompt, but not in cron</strike> Err, doesn't work in either shell or cron (but should...?):

```
 53 notify_dba "${FRIENDLY_SERVER_NAME}: New ORA errors in AlertLog" echo ${
 54 "Please check full log in ${ALERT_LOG_LOCATION}.
 55 =====================================================
 56 `grep -A900000 "${LAST_LINE_FROM_ARCHIVE}:" ${TEMPORARY_LOG_WITH_ORA_ERRORS} | grep -v "${LAST_LINE_FROM_ARCHIVE}:"`
 57 =====================================================
 58 "}
```

Getting the error:

```
Wed Jan 16 06:00:01 PST 2019
LAST_LINE_FROM_ARCHIVE=449843
LAST_LINE_FROM_TEMP= 452866
/u01/app/oracle/admin/chk_alertlog.sh: line 53: ${
"Please check full log in ${ALERT_LOG_LOCATION}.
=====================================================
`grep -A900000 "${LAST_LINE_FROM_ARCHIVE}:" ${TEMPORARY_LOG_WITH_ORA_ERRORS} | grep -v "${LAST_LINE_FROM_ARCHIVE}:"`
=====================================================
"}: bad substitution
```

Comment: Ok, I was wondering how could it possibly work in a shell... But you just made your edit. The unquoted `${` triggers parameter substitution, which gives you the `bad substitution` error. Why the curly braces surrounding your block? They seem just wrong there.

Comment: lol, the shell hit a condition and this was the first time this block of code hit... I'll try without the curly braces - the thought was that being a multi-line string argument that I might have to encapsulate with squirrelies ..

Comment: Seems to have done the trick. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Glad to hear that. Even if I'm late, I'm posting an answer with some examples on handling multi-line and non-fixed text in scripts.

Comment: Pleased to see you're already sorted. In general, please don't post code with line numbers. It adds work in cutting and pasting the example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment to your question, the error you see is due to the unquoted `${`, which triggers parameter expansion (see "Parameter Expansion" in section "EXPANSION" of [`man bash`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html)).

That said, you can of course pass around a multi-line text block. You have just to quote it properly:

If it is static, single quotes are ok:

```bash
$ mlblock='line 1
> line 2'
$ printf '%s\n' "$mlblock"
line 1
line 2
```

If you want it to be built at execution time, you have to use double quotes, which preserve the special meaning of `$`, `` ` `` and `\`, allowing, [among other things](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_03), parameter expansion and command substitution:

```bash
$ text="Sample    text"
$ mlblock="$text
> date: $(date)
> end"
$ printf '%s\n' "$mlblock"
Sample    text
date: Wed Jan 16 22:18:33 CET 2019
end
```

Note that expansions appearing anywhere in a string enclosed in double quotes are themselves quoted. Thus, their spacing is preserved (e.g. `Sample    text`).

The most readable way to pass a complex string to a function is probably to use a variable:

```bash
$ function notify_dba () {
    printf '%s\n' "$1"    # Print header
    printf '%s\n' "$2"    # Print body
}
$ notify_dba 'Header' "$mlblock" 
Header
Sample    text
date: Wed Jan 16 22:21:14 CET 2019
end
```

Note that the second argument has to appear in double quotes because: 1) if unquoted, it would be expanded by the shell and, when resulting in more than one word, be translated into *more than one arguments* to the function; 2) if surrounded by single quotes, it would be interpreted literally as the string `$mlblock`.

Alternatively you can, of course, build the argument string as you call your function:

```bash
$ notify_dba 'Header' "Multi
> line body
> date: $(date)
> end"
Header
Multi
line body
date: Wed Jan 16 22:29:13 CET 2019
end
```